# How to issue notifications that echo across all open consoles of particular user?

Tags: notification, libnotify, notify-send

I've heard about `notify-send` of libnotify-bin, but it only seems purposed for GUI desktops.

Is there a simpler counterpart that's just for consoles? Similar to the warning/notification we get when Ubuntu is shutdown or reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The venerable `write` and `wall` commands do what you are looking for.

```
write user [tty]
```

will echo whatever it reads from stdin to the terminal that *user* is using, or to a specific terminal.

The `wall` command (**w** rite to **all**) notifies all console users at once. This is the command used by `shutdown`.

Comment: How can we do the same for pts?

Comment: @veerendragupta do you mean this doesn't work for you?

Comment: my bad! for pts(remotely logged in terminals) it is working fine but if terminal is open within desktop session it doesn't send message to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `wall` command might give you what you need.
Here is an example:

`echo "Hello World" | wall`

Users can turn off these messages (check by running `mesg`) but if you run the command as root this setting will be ignored.